# how to limit a regular expression to the closest in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Assuming I have:

```
[24] pry(main)> str="these (are) things (that) I want (to) know"
```

and I want

```
=> ["these", "things", "I want", "know"]
```

but

```
[25] pry(main)> str.split(/\(.*\)/)
```

I get:

```
=> ["these ", " know"]
[26] pry(main)>
```

How would I fix this? Sorry for multiple questions - a bit seperate issues.

## edit #1

since we're splitting on a Regex, is there any way to also get the matched elements back?
like:

=> [["these", "things", "I want", "know"],["(are)","(that)","(too)"]]

where the first part is the splitted values and the second is the matched array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `*` quantifier ungreedy by putting a `?` after it. Like so:

```
str.split(/\(.*?\)/)
```

`.*` without `?` will match as much as possible, while you want the opposite effect.

You could also use a different approach and restrict what characters you want to match. For example:

```
str.split(/\([^()]*\)/)
```

Comment: cool! thx, is there any way I can get the capture elements like (are),(that) in an array?

Comment: @timpone, not sure what you mean. Add some example input string and the desired output.

Comment: sorry - I updated I was trying to get the capture elements via the regex used for the split; I updated the question with an edit for the output I was hoping to get.

Comment: @timpone, if you also want the words in `()` I think you could use `str.split(/(\([^()]*\))/)` (assuming split in Ruby works the same as in Perl and similar languages). If you do not want the `()` words in the same array you are probably better off not using split, but just do some matches in a loop.

Comment: thx - I think brings it back in original array; but gets me a lot further. thx again!

Comment: `str.split(/\(.*?\)/) => ["these ", " things ", " I want ", " know"]`.  I think you need to tweak that: `str.split(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/)
=> ["these", "things", "I want", "know"]`.  Ditto for the second form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
[str.gsub(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/, 0.chr).split(0.chr), str.scan(/(\(.*?\))/).flatten]
  #=> [["these", "things", "I want", "know"], ["(are)", "(that)", "(to)"]]
```

I could have `gsub`'ed to any string I was certain was not in the data.  ASCII 0 seemed a safe choice. `split` is definitely better for the first element, but I offer this in the interest of diversity.

Answer (score 1):

Non regexp version:

```
s = "these (are) things (that) I want (to) know"
is_parenthesised = -> x {x.start_with?('(') && x.end_with?(')')}
p s.split(' ').partition &is_parenthesised #=> [["(are)", "(that)", "(to)"], ["these", "things", "I", "want", "know"]]
```

Comment: "I want" is required.  Maybe change `split`'s argument to a regex, but I expect you wanted to avoid that.  btw, that's a lovely-reading lambda.